# Is there a way to setup bluemix as $DOCKER_HOST and use it with the docker binary?

Tags: api, docker, command-line-interface, ibm-cloud

I am trying to use Bluemix to run automated builds inside docker. My CI system can already work with the normal docker cli and in combination with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable I am able to run docker commands on other machines.
Is there a way to connect the docker binary to Bluemix? Or a other API beside the cf cli to start and stop containers on Bluemix?

Comment: could you please provide examples of commands you are trying to run? That way someone can try to help with Bluemix containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the normal Docker CLI with IBM Containers.

When you run the $ cf ic login command the following text gives you the details.

```
Option 2) Leverage the docker CLI directly. In this shell, override local docker environment to connect to IBM Containers by setting these variables, copy and paste the following:
    Notice: only commands with an asterisk(*) are supported within this option

    export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net:8443
    export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/username/.ice/certs
    export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```